# Python Type Hint for Returning Concrete Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, pylance

I have some code (attached below) that I'm running with Python 3.10.

The code runs fine, but pylance in VS Code flags an error for these lines:

```py
books: list[SoftBack] = [softback_book_1, softback_book_2]
processed_books = BookProcessor(books).process()
```

This is because the `BookProcessor` class type hints say that it will take a `list[Book]` and return a `list[Book]`. Whereas I'm actually giving it a `list[SoftBack]` and expecting it to return a `list[SoftBack]`, as `SoftBack` is a concrete class of `Book`.

The error is:

```
(variable) books: list[SoftBack]
Argument of type "list[SoftBack]" cannot be assigned to parameter "books" of type "list[Book]" in function "__init__"
  "list[SoftBack]" is incompatible with "list[Book]"
    TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
      "SoftBack" is incompatible with "Book" Pylancereport(GeneralTypeIssues)
```

Should I be using a different type hint for returning concrete classes, or is pylance incorrect in flagging this up? (Or am I doing Python wrong?!).

```py
"""
Book Testing
"""

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import Any

class Book(ABC):
    """
    A generic book.
    """

    name: str

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, *args: Any | None, **kwargs: Any | None) -> None:
        """
        Abstract initialiser.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

class SoftBack(Book):
    """
    A softback book.
    """

    name: str

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

class BookProcessor:
    """
    A simple book processor.
    """

    books: list[Book]

    def __init__(self, books: list[Book]) -> None:
        self.books = books

    def process(self) -> list[Book]:
        """
        Add the string '_processed' to book names,
        returning a new list of books.
        """
        processed_books: list[Book] = []
        for book in self.books:
            new_book = deepcopy(book)
            new_book.name += '_processed'
            processed_books.append(new_book)
        return processed_books

def main():
    """
    Main function.
    """
    softback_book_1 = SoftBack(name='book_01')
    softback_book_2 = SoftBack(name='book_02')
    books: list[SoftBack] = [softback_book_1, softback_book_2]
    processed_books = BookProcessor(books).process()
    for processed_book in processed_books:
        print(processed_book.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A `list[Book]` is a list you can *add* arbitrary books to. You can't do that with a `list[SoftBack]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `BookProcessor` generic so that you can capture the exact type of `Book` being processed.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


B = TypeVar('B', bound=Book)


class BookProcessor(Generic[B]):
    """
    A simple book processor.
    """

    books: list[B]

    def __init__(self, books: list[B]) -> None:
        self.books = books

    def process(self) -> list[B]:
        """
        Add the string '_processed' to book names,
        returning a new list of books.
        """
        processed_books: list[B] = []
        for book in self.books:
            new_book = deepcopy(book)
            new_book.name += '_processed'
            processed_books.append(new_book)
        return processed_books
```

When you instantiate `BookProcessor` with a list of `SoftBook`s, the value of `B` will be "bound" to `SoftBook` to make the type `BookProcess[SoftBook]`, giving you the desired return type of `list[SoftBook]` for `process`.

Comment: This works, thanks. Though I must admit I'm not sure why. Probably because I don't understand TypeVar and Generic, and reading PEP 484 didn't help. So B is a TypeVar, which means it's a variable that can describe any type, but it's bound to Book, so it can only really be a Book or its subclasses(?). So why do we need a Generic, if "B" already describes a Book? Further, why does BookProcessor need to be a subclass of a Generic[B]? Can't it process a list[B] without being a child of Generic[B]?

Comment: `Generic` means that for each particular *instance* of `BookProcessor`, a *distinct* class can be bound to `B` whereever it is found. Think of the class as actually being a "function" with a parameter `B`, and the first time you use something that requires `B` to have a particular value, that value is remembered for the life of the instance. In this case, when you first instantiate the class, the type used for the `books` argument sets the value of `B` for that instance.

Comment: So `BookProcessor` can produce "concrete" classes like `BookProcessor[Book]`, `BookProcessor[SoftBook]`, etc. The bound on `B` does, in fact, mean that only `Book` or a subclass is a suitable value for `B`. (`BookProcessor` isn't really a child of `Generic` in the usual OOP sense; this is mainly an abuse of syntax to define the function-like mapping I alluded to in the previous comment.)

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. It looks like I need to read up on this kind of thing!